# Using C programming language instead of Processing with Arduino

Tags: c, arduino, processing

How can i use "Plain C" to program Arduino without using the "Processing programming language"?
I want to improve my C programming skills by using it with Arduino for embedded systems.

I have very limited ability to code in C++, and I would love to write my own Arduino Library using "C", to avoid using classes and OOP.

Processing looks like Java to me, and i want to use "C pointers" to gain more practical knowledge.

Comment: why dont you just get a beaglebone.

Comment: Processing IS Java and as noted in some of the answers, Arduino doesn't use Processing (it simply borrowed some code for the IDE). Libraries in Arduino are just C++ classes. You can write all your code in C if you like.

Comment: google has quite a lot of hits when you search for programming an arduino using C. Doing your own searching before posting (or mentioning you searched, what on, and that there were no useful results) is expected of you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is that **Arduino doesn't use Processing.**

Processing is (was?) a separate programming language which was developed independently for a different purpose. The language resembles C and C++ very closely, so closely that it's almost identical.

Programming the Arduino, however, is accomplished using **a (n unfortunate) mixture of C and C++,** with a set of custom libraries (which are similar in style to that of Processing). **These libraries are written in C and C++ themselves,** and they are only good for making one's code more portable across different MCU types. **Using them is not strictly necessary for programming the AVR MCU.** In fact, the libraries have quite a few drawbacks (the code is big, inherently slow and ugly, amongst others).

If you want to use plain ol' C for programming the Arduino, then just go ahead and do so. Grab the reference PDF from Atmel's site for your particular MCU, learn the special registers (I/O, timers, etc.), install the avr-gcc toolchain on your computer, and use `avr-gcc`, `avr-objcopy` and `avrdude` to compile and install your programs.

There also [happens to be a C-only library](https://github.com/H2CO3/libavrutil) which follows this kind of convention. It doesn't provide as much abstraction as the stock Arduino library has, because it's lower-level, but you can have a look at it and see how one can accomplish basic algorithms without the default libraries.

Comment: Processing is Java-based and you can use all the regular Java libs, etc. Concerning Arduino libraries, it may be a matter of opinion, but they really are only C++ classes. There is nothing inherently slow or large in size with using them, and there are no "inherent drawbacks" to using them. Some of the libs which ship with Arduino are intended for basic, all purpose, beginner usage - which is consistent with the audience the Arduino is intended for.

Comment: @TOMATO Once I have measured the performance of the Arduino libraries. They are generally one or two order of magnitude (!) slower than "raw" code that uses the registers immediately. This really is inherent, since it's the result of its authors' will to provide a cross-platform library, i. e. one that doesn't depend on the actual MCU type. For this, they needed to introduce quite a bit of indirection and abstraction in the code (for example, arrays of pointers which point to the appropriate special-purpose registers). As to what matters and what doesn't: don't judge without knowing...

Comment: @TOMATO ...what one's goal is. Generalization is bad. Back then I **had to** quit using the stock Arduino libs because they weren't fast enough for the use case I encountered.

Comment: You apparently completely miss the point of the Arduino project. It's purpose was and is to abstract away the low level details and provide a relatively easy learning curve for people interested in working with physical computing. Given the popularity of Arduino, its creators were correct in their choices. For most users of Arduino, ease of use clearly trumps any loss of a few cycles or bytes and for advanced users, nothing precludes the use of custom code. So it's a win all around. Making a blanket statement that libraries are "bad" is just silly.

Comment: @TOMATO You apparently completely miss that I was not stating that the libraries are bad.